# Keyboard shortcut as clickable shortcut?

Tags: windows

Is there any option to make keyboard shortcuts clickable? I need for example Win + Z as clickable shortcut on the desktop. Is this possible in any simple way?

Comment: What do you mean by a "clickable shortcut" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn a keyboard shortcut into a Desktop shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/400628/how-to-turn-a-keyboard-shortcut-into-a-desktop-shortcut)

Comment: By clickable shortcut I mean an icon on the desktop that launches when clicked, I don't know how else to say this? is it not clear?

Comment: none of what is linked works with windows key and they all just execute scripts? I just need an icon on the desktop that does "Win + z" when it is clicked, is that even possible?

Comment: That's because what you want is a system level shortcut so the only way you're going to be able to trigger it (anyone can correct me if i'm wrong) is by using third party software.

Comment: @HelpIIII: All icons on the desktop launch something when clicked. Or do you mean an icon that can be launched by a click *and* by a hotkey?

Comment: No I have no idea what you still understand. When you install software, It adds a little picture where you click and it opens it. I need just that. Literally just a desktop icon that launches something!

Comment: What is it that the Win+Z shortcut does for you? Open the app bar?

Comment: I am not sure what info you guys need. So it is not possible to just have an icon that does Win + Z when clicked?

Comment: what happens when you press Win + Z on your keyboard?

Comment: It opens the window layout box, I need that clickable from desktop (not hover, not keyboard shortcut, not anything else)

Comment: I use a combination of AHK and RainMeter

Comment: First, I find the question clear enough. Second, many keyboard shortcuts are contextual, and when you click a desktop icon, it is unlikely THAT is the context you want the shortcut operating within. For that reason, this question is not just "how do I make a clickable 'keyboard shortcut'", because you are dealing with a specific shortcut whose context is NOT impacted by a mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

The below will bind Win+Z to a double click on your mouse scroll button, which should be more convenient than a desktop shortcut. If you still prefer the desktop shortcut then let me know.

Download [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). This is the macro scripting free software that will resolve your issue.

Right-Click an empty area on your desktop and create a new AutoHotKey Script

[image]

Open the AHK file in notepad and copy/paste the below code into it

```
  ; Set a flag to keep track of double-clicks
doubleClickFlag := false

; Define a hotkey for the mouse scroll wheel button (usually MButton)
MButton::
    ; Check if the flag is set (indicating a double-click)
    if (doubleClickFlag) {
        ; Send Win + Z shortcut
        Send, #z
        ; Reset the flag
        doubleClickFlag := false
    } else {
        ; Set the flag to true to indicate a potential double-click
        doubleClickFlag := true
        ; Set a timer to reset the flag after a short delay (adjust as needed)
        SetTimer, ResetDoubleClickFlag, 300 ; 300 milliseconds
    }
    return

; This subroutine resets the double-click flag
ResetDoubleClickFlag:
    doubleClickFlag := false
    return
```

Save/close notepad > right click the AHK file and click on "Compile Script". This will turn it into a green autohotkey .exe file on your desktop.

[image]

Copy the exe file into this location:

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Now restart your computer and the EXE script will run automatically each time you log into your computer. You can tell the script is running by observing the green "H" icon in your task tray.

[image]

You should now find Win+Z can be launched with a double click of your mouse scroll button.

Comment: I actually, specifically need it as a clickable desktop shortcut, it should not require mouse scroll button or anything like that

Comment: does this run on start, if yes why? Can't I just have "Win + Z" remaining on desktop and be only executed if I click on it? again, nothing else should be there (no mouse scroll etc nothing)

Comment: I don't really know what all of this is. Is there no easy way to have Win + Z clickable on desktop, like any other program, when it is needed?

Comment: You could modify the above AHK script to be triggered with a batch script that you place on your desktop i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, and each link would be made differently, **depending on the function of the shortcut.** What is <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> supposed to do? Make the link to that function. for example:

- To make a clickable desktop shortcut to **<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>**, the ***Run*** dialog,

  - Right-click the Desktop.
  - Select *New > Shortcut*.
  - Paste the following into the location of the item:

    ```
    explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
    ```
  - Click *Next*.
  - Type a name for the shortcut, such as *Win-R* or *Run*.
  - Click *Finish*.

In Windows 11, specifically, **<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>** opens [***Snap Layout*** settings](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-snap-layouts-enable-disable/). To create a shortcut to that dialog, proceed as above, but paste the following as the location:

```
ms-settings:multitasking
```

For a list of the *ms-settings* shortcuts, see [Windows OS Hub](https://woshub.com/ms-settings-uri-commands-windows-11/).